# Is there a way to sync google sheets and MySQL so that an edit in the google sheets table will update the table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'd like to use google apps script to sync MySQL and google sheets so that someone can edit a google sheets table and it will update a corresponding MySQL table.

I have connected MySQL and google sheets so that I can run queries (including update queries) in google apps script that return a MySQL table. Just not the other way around.

Comment: Possible. You're probably sending `SELECT...WHERE...` query. You should send `INSERT...` query on each edit

Answer (score 4):

I've had a problem similar to yours and I got an answer to it [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367331/how-to-query-my-database-and-have-it-be-outputted-on-a-google-sheet-so-that-some), hopefully it can also help you.

It presents a few solutions: Google Apps Script, Zapier, Kloud, Blockspring and Actiondesk.